# Why does Windows App and Browser Protection turn itself off by default?

Tags: bug

I can't turn on App and Browser protection in Windows Security. I recently installed Malwarebytes. Can anyone please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not be happening. A third party software should not be able to change your settings unless you give permission for it to do that. You should probably remove Malwarebytes, and try it then.

Because you have given it permission, you may be able to change the App and Browser protection on Malwarebytes.

I suggest using Avast as it has fewer hassles, and i find it a better Antivirus and malware detector. It also has many handy features.